# UTF-8 POST received by IIS as ASCII

Tags: post, utf-8, iis-10

I have a webpage (IIS version 10.0.16299.15 under Windows 10) whose head element contains:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

From this page I do a POST using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    type: "POST",
    url: "hierarchy.lib.asp?action=save",
    data: {
        nameFrench: $("#frenchName").val()
    },

    ...
```

I know that UTF-8 is the default, but I explicitly set it while trying to fix this issue.

The POSTed value is the word "Écrou". A break point in the Javascript shows "Écrou" is being posted.

When I receive the posted data, the result seems to be ASCII encoded.

```
dim value: value = request.form("nameFrench")
```

The variable `value` now contains value "Ã‰crou" (checked while debugging with Visual Studio).

Could IIS incorrectly be encoding the request collection with ASCII-encoded values instead of the POSTed UTF-8 strings?

I know there was a bug like this in IIS 7.5:
https://www.redolive.com/utah-web-designers-blog/how-to-fix-utf-8charset-problem-with-iis-7-5-and-php-fastcgi/

Thoughts?

**Edit**

If I replace:

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
```

with:

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" codepage=65001 %>
```

Then my value POSTed from jQuery's ajax is correct when received at server-side. However, this change breaks POSTing using standard HTML forms even from web pages that use the meta tag to declare they are UTF-8 pages.

I tried changing the Ajax call to POST just like the windows forms:

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
```

But that doesn't fix the issue.

I also tried with:

```
contentType: 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1',
```

and:

```
contentType: 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1252',
```

When I POST with jQuery ajax using 8859 (having changed nothing else except the html meta tag) the POST is completely empty, no body is sent to the server at all!

On server side if I check `Session.CodePage` or `response.CodePage` they both return 1252.

Comment: I don't think it's the role of the IIS server per se to do such HTTP body decoding. Are you using ASP?, ASP.NET? Please [edit] to add tags and explanation. BTW—"Ã‰crou" isn't ASCII of course. Assuming that UTF-8 was sent, the mojibake comes from decoding it as [Windows-1252 or Windows-1254](http://share.linqpad.net/3xq3sr.linq) or something on your machine and not on mine.

Comment: It's ASP Classic. Request.Form("nameFrench") returns the value but the accented character is as described. And like I said, this was a known bug in IIS 7.5 where the request.Form collection was ASCII encoded, this issue seems very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I re-read the jQuery docs for Ajax. It seems I mis-read them before. Although you can set the contentType, and that changes the POST headers, it does not seem to force browsers to POST the data with the encoding you specify. It does change what is POSTed, but it does not correctly (at least according to my expextations) re-encode the posted data.

So I had to change this `<%@ Language="VBScript" %>` to this `<%@ Language="VBScript" codepage=65001 %>` and make sure my web page was using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

... which by the way doesn't seem compatible with my existing HTML Forms that may POST user-entered accented characters. When I post this way the server-side request.form collection seems to be ASCII encoded (The accented characters replaced with `?`).